# Count on result of Case statements in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi i am getting a different value when i interchange the case statement line above and below. Which is not good. Can some body help me on this

```
SELECT
    CASE 
     WHEN dDate > '20130509' ANd dDate < '20130909' THEN 1
     WHEN dDate > '20130609' ANd dDate < '20131109' THEN 2
     WHEN dDate > '20130709' ANd dDate < '20131009' THEN 3 as DateVal,
CASE 
     WHEN dDate > '20130509' ANd dDate < '20130909' THEN COUNT(Encounter)
     WHEN dDate > '20130609' ANd dDate < '20131109' THEN COUNT(Encounter)
     WHEN dDate > '20130709' ANd dDate < '20131009' THEN COUNT(Encounter)) as Value
FROM Table 1
```

Result of the above query is

```
 EncounterCount     Date
 230                 1
 45                  2
 20                  3
```

When the change the above query slightly

```
SELECT
        CASE 
         WHEN dDate > '20130609' ANd dDate < '20131109' THEN 2
         **WHEN dDate > '20130509' ANd dDate < '20130909' THEN 1**
         WHEN dDate > '20130709' ANd dDate < '20131009' THEN 3 as DateVal,
    CASE 
         WHEN dDate > '20130609' ANd dDate < '20131109' THEN COUNT(Encounter)
         **WHEN dDate > '20130509' ANd dDate < '20130909' THEN COUNT(Encounter)**
         WHEN dDate > '20130709' ANd dDate < '20131009' THEN COUNT(Encounter)) as Value
    FROM Table 1
```

The result is like :
Result of the above query is

```
 EncounterCount     Date
 45                 1
 150                2
 20                 3
```

This is very strange to me. Can anybody help.

Comment: This happens because you are overlapping the date ranges, and `CASE` generally chooses the first correct expression that meets the criteria

Comment: Is your date format is yyyymmdd or yyyyddmm?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the date intervals you specified in `WHEN` clauses overlap. When the `CASE` statement finds a matching `WHEN` clause, it gets the result form that clause and skips the other ones.

Some of your records can match in more than one `WHEN` clause. When you reorder the clauses, you change the chance of rows to match against another `WHEN` clause.